# How to access image by url on s3 using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyramid, boto

What I want to accomplish is to generate a link to view the file (ex.image or pdf). The item is not accessible by URL (https://[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/img_name.jpg), I think because its private and not public? (I'm not the owner of the bucket, but he gave me the access_key and secret_key?)

For now, all I can do is to download a file with this code.

```
s3.Bucket('mybucket').download_file('upload/nocturnes.png', 'dropzone/static/pdf/download_nocturnes.png')
```

I want to access an image on s3 so I can put it on an HTML, can I view it using the access and secret key?. Thank you for those who can help!

Comment: If there is a high volume of traffic to retrieve the file, don't do this direct file retrieval.

Comment: @mootmoot why? and how should I do retrieval?

Comment: Study option to use CDN. Because AWS is charging $0.09/GB for data transfer out from AWS that not using cloudfront.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a pre-signed URL using the [`generate_presigned_url`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url) function. The caveat is that pre-signed URLs must have an expiration date. I was unable to find documentation on the maximum allowed duration. Here is an example:

```
url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                Params={
                                    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
                                    'Key': 'upload/nocturnes.png',
                                },                                  
                                ExpiresIn=3600)
print url
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for. I can finally put the image from s3 to my site. But I have a new problem, I'm using a js library (pdf.js) to view the pdf file from amazon to my site. But it produce a "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ....." but its another question, thanks again.

Comment: @jordanm in case you're curious, the maximum time that works in every AWS region is 604800 seconds (7 days).  Older regions appear to support expirations beyond year 2038 if the URL is signed with Signature Version 2, but 7 days is the value that works everywhere.  If the access-key-id that signed the URL is disabled/deleted, any URLs signed by that key also become unusable, and since access key rotation is a best practice, signed URLs only last as long as your key rotation policy allows.

Answer (score 2):

For people who want to use `generate_presigned_url` for a public object and therefore don't want to do the signing part that appends credentials, the best solution I found is to still to use the `generate_presigned_url`, just that the `Client.Config.signature_version` needs to be set to `botocore.UNSIGNED`.

The following returns the public link without the signing stuff.

```
config.signature_version = botocore.UNSIGNED
boto3.client('s3', config=config).generate_presigned_url('get_object', ExpiresIn=0, Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key})
```

The relevant discussions on the boto3 repository are:

- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/110
- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/169
- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1415