# How to point Django .html to S3 media file? AccessDenied

Tags: python, html, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can upload files to the S3 bucket from my django app using the models admin view. I can also view the video within my django app admin view.
But I am not able to view the video via the django **.html** file.

Here is my **models.py** file

```
from project_4.storage_backends import MediaStorage

class video(models.Model):
    videofile = models.FileField(storage=MediaStorage(), null=True, verbose_name="", unique=True)
```

I created a **storage_backends.py** under my app project folder

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION
    default_acl = 'private'  # To turn access control list into private use only. Will use it in models.py
    file_overwrite = False  # Not to replace files even they have same name
    custom_domain = False
```

In my **settings.py** I added the following

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'x'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'x'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'django-draft-project-1'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "eu-central-1"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"

# AWS S3 Private Media Upload
AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
PRIVATE_FILE_STORAGE = 'project_4.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=94608000',
}
```

At this point, I am able to upload and view my video through the admin console. Now I would like the video to be viewable within my html.

```
<video controls>
<source src={{ S3_URL }}{{ detailedview.video_name }}>
</video>
```

The `{{ S3_URL }}{{ detailedview.video_name }}` yields the root URL I see in the admin page which is `https://django-draft-project-1.s3.amazonaws.com/media/SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4` however pasting this url directing causes `<Code>AccessDenied</Code>`

The actual admin url on top when I play the video is

```
https://django-draft-project-1.s3.amazonaws.com/media/SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=wewe-HMAC-wewe&X-Amz-Credential=wewewe%2F20190401%wwewwe-central-1%2Fs3%wewe&X-Amz-Date=20190401T053817Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&ewew-Signature=123456qwertasdfzxcvasdfwert
```

Moreover, my object url on the s3 console is Object URL

```
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/django-draft-project-1/media/SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4
```

But also using it directly yields `<Code>AccessDenied</Code>`

How can I fix the access denied within my .html so I can play the media file back to the user?

Comment: But you've set the default ACL to private. So you won't be able to link to it publicly. Why have you done that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access image by url on s3 using boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973658/how-to-access-image-by-url-on-s3-using-boto3)

Comment: @DanielRoseman the goal is to make the video contents only accessible via the Django .html hosted page, and not via a user copy/pasting the URL straight in the browser i.e. not through `https://django-draft-project-1.s3.amazonaws.com/media/SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4`, but rather through having the correct paramters(AWSAccessKeyId, Signature, Expires) or a more secure form where the user cannot share the video links without going through the website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a presigned URL. Django-storages will actually take care of this if you access the file in the right way, which is to use the `url` property of the field. So:

```
<source src="{{ detailedview.video_name.url }}">
```

This also takes care of prefixing with the S3 URL. Note, the `url` property itself isn't special to django-storages; that's how you are always supposed to generate the URL for a media file.